# Delphi Storing data in Array and retrieve it

Tags: delphi

i need to store a two strings in an Array like this, and retrieve values in another function to use it.

| Date Start | Date End |
| --- | --- |
| VALUE_START | VALUE_END |
| VALUE_START2 | VALUE_END2 |

I think the correct ways is to use this variable `StoringData : TArray<String>`, but how can i valorized it with VALUE_START and VALUE_END ?

Comment: `type TPeriod = record StartDate, EndDate: TDate; end` and `var Data: array[0..1] of TPeriod` if you want a [static array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays) and `var Data: TArray<TPeriod>` if you want a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays). Remember that dynamic arrays are reference types. Or, use a `TList<TPeriod>` if you want a simpler API to work against and can live with having to create and free the list heap object.

Comment: And I might also advice you to buy a good book about Delphi programming and read it carefully so you learn the language properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to define a data type that can hold two string:

```
type
    TPeriod = record
        DateStart : String;     // Isn't TDateTime better than String here ?
        DateEnd   : String;
    end;
```

Then you can declare a dynamic array if that data type

```
var
    StoringData : TArray<TPeriod>;
```

At some point, you must allocate space for the array (This is a dynamic array so no space allocated when it is declared)

```
SetLength(StoringData, TheSizeYouNeed);
```

The you can access the array elements like this:

```
StoringData[0].DateStart := '04/05/2021';
StoringData[0].DateEnd   := '06/05/2021';
StoringData[1].DateStart := '04/06/2021';
StoringData[1].DateEnd   := '06/06/2021';
```

You don't need to free the allocated space, it will be done automatically, but you can if you need to reclaim memory. Call SetLength with a zero size.

You can resize the array. Existing data will be kept (If you size down, some will of course be lost):

```
SetLength(StoringData, 3);   // Add a third more row
// Assign a value
StoringData[2].DateStart := '04/07/2021';
StoringData[2].DateEnd   := '06/07/2021';
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, my code right now is this
`StoringData       : TArray<String>; `
`SetLength(StoringData,2);`
           `for x := 0 to High(StoringData) do`
            `for c := 0 to High(StoringData[x]) do`
             `begin`
                `StoringData[x] := DataCovertedS;`
                `StoringData[c] := TotTime;`
             ` end;`

Comment: No need for a record type. Use a 2-dimensional array instead, if you like

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes 2D array, but i'm not able to store [c] on the second column do you know why ?

Comment: A record is much better than a 2D array: a record can have methods ! For example, you can add a method to initialize the record at once, or to get/set the values from/to TDateTime and much more. Also with a record, you can easily add more members without breaking existent code. Records in Delphi are first class citizen, much like classes. 2D array are old school.

Comment: @Marcol1no you have to set the length for both dimensions: ``SetLength(array, 2, 2)``

Comment: The settings is correct SetLength(array, 2) but now i need to creare more rows ... It only adds the first date start and date stop

Comment: Reread my last comment, please. And watch the syntax carefully.

Comment: @DelphiCoder By setting `SetLength(StoringData,2,2)`  it tells me error that expect ')' and not ',' ... Rows needs to be dinamyc and column static

Comment: @Marcol1no I edited my answer to add a resize example (adding a 3rd row).

Comment: @Marcol1no maybe you use an outdated Delphi version

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2-dimensional array with the first dimension being dynamic, and the second one static:

```
TYPE
  TPeriod = ARRAY[1..2] OF STRING;
  TPeriods = TArray<TPeriod>;

VAR
  Periods : TPeriods;

BEGIN
  SetLength(Periods,2);
  Periods[0,1]:='Start Date 1';
  Periods[0,2]:='End Date 1';
  Periods[1,1]:='Start Date 2';
  Periods[1,2]:='End Date 2';
END.
```

Comment: Much less readable than a record, much more prone to errors.